# Are there trophies for Zen Pinball 2 on the PS Vita?

Tags: ps-vita, zen-pinball-2

Just downloaded Zen Pinball 2 and the Plant vs. Zombies table. When you click the trophies icon on the game it tells me to buy new tables. I thought I just did... Is there just no trophy support for that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a problem with the trophies for Zen Pinball 2 on the PS Vita. According to this Tweet [Zen Studio's is working on it](https://twitter.com/adamguest1985/status/243787911609323521).

---

### Update 1

Apparently it is location related. It affects users in the EU and it's [still not fixed](https://twitter.com/zen_studios/status/245607559527030784).

---

### Update 2

Trophies appeared on the PS Vita for me after I bought the Avengers Chronicles pack even though I installed the classic tables pack. On the PS3 the game just unlocked (and had trophies) after installing the classic tables pack.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are a couple of trophies associated with the Plants vs. Zombies table, see the bottom of [this page](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/zen-pinball-2-vita/trophies/):

> - **Letter from Mom** (Bronze)
>     Lock three balls and start You Have Mail Multiball on the Plants vs. Zombies table.
> - **Malfunction** (Silver)
>     Confront Dr. Zomboss and triumph over his giant Zombot on the Plants vs. Zombies table.

Comment: That's weird, there should be trophies for the old tables as well.. I don't see the entire game in the trophy list.

Comment: There is indeed a problem with the trophies on the Vita. [Zen Studio's is working on it](https://twitter.com/adamguest1985/status/243787911609323521).